# Submit dynamic form asynchronously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

- I want to be able to dynamically add text fields whenever the button
  is clicked
- I want to be able to get the data from the text fields and insert it
  into the database.
- As of now everything else works and I just need this, maybe I can
  also add a remove button to remove the last text field dynamically
  also
- the reason why I need this to be dynamic is because I don't want to
  refresh the page cause all the data will be lost
- I have found a code that would help me dynamically add text fields
  but I don't know how to make it so that I would need to go to another
  page just to access data

---

```
<html>
<form action="checklist3.php" method="post">
    <button type='submit' name='submit' id='buttonParent'>Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="back">Back</button>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../mysql_connect.php');
    $rowarray = $_SESSION['rowarray'];
    $dishname = $_SESSION['dishname'];


    echo '<br>';
    echo "Add Procedures";
    echo ' <form name="addproc" id="addproc">
                <table class="proctable" id="proctable">  
                                        <tr>  
                                             <td><input type="text" name="procedure[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                             <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                        </tr>  
                                   </table>  
                        </form>';


    echo "<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>";
    echo "<body>";


    echo "</body>";

    if (isset($_POST['home'])) {
        header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/chefmenu.php");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['back'])) {
        header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/checklist2.php");
    }

    ?>

</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function () {
            i++;
            $('#proctable').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Procedure" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
        });
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'name.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $('#addproc').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#addproc')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do with a little of jquery and AJAX :

1. Create and `append` a field to your form using jquery, something like
2. Capture your form sumission with jquery event listeners : `$("form").live("submit", function (e){e.preventDefault()...}`
3. Serialize all your form (with the newly added fields) and send them via AJAX

An example of code :

```
    $("form").live("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action'), // Get the action URL to send AJAX to
          type: "POST",
          data: form.serialize(), // get all form variables
          success: function(result){
              // ... do your AJAX post result
          }
      });
  });
```